# Relations in Laravel and How to show it in blade

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I looking for simple way to build invoice system I think about Laravel because I know a little PHP and MySQL. 
I have problem with understanding how create Relations between tables and show it.
For exaple:
I have tables:

User
-id
-username
...

Client
-id
-name
-address
...

Product
-id
-name
-price
...

Invoice
-id
-client_id -> foregin
-user_id -> foregin
-number
-product_id -> foregin

How to connect it in Laravel

User have some Client and this Client have Invoice with Prducts

and show in Invoice list and User can Add new Invoice for Client etc...

Regards,
Andrew

Comment: can you put some more effort on your question. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start of with a migration command

```
php artisan make:migration CreateProductsTable
```

Define your structure in here, so it looks something like this:

```
Schema::create('products', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('sku')->unique();
        $table->double('price');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

After this you need to create a model:

```
php artisan make:model Product
```

Which creates an Product.php file in your "App" folder

```
    class Product
{

    /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'sku', 'price'
    ];

}
```

If a field is not defined in $fillable you will be unable to post the field.

Now create a ProductController

```
php artisan make:controller ProductController
```

this has to look like something like this:

```
        class ProductController extends Controller
    {

        public function __construct()
        {
            //$this->middleware('auth');
        }

        public function index(Request $request) {
            $data = $request->all();

            $product= Product::create([
                'name' => $data['product_name'],
                'sku' => $data['product_sku'],
                'price' => $data['product_price'],
            ]);
        }
}
```

Of course you can add fields like user_id in the products table, so set relationships between different tables.

Answer (score 0):

> NOTE : The following example is just for the sake of demonsteration

First you need to establish the relation type in your models

For Eg: (One to Many Relation) **Users** & **Products** tables, One User can buy many products and the product bought belongs to each user only.

So its **One** to **Many**

In your **User.php** Model you need to add

```
public function products(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Product');
}
```

In your **Product.php** Model you need to add

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
}
```

While getting the users you can get related products to that user by the following query

```
/* products inside with is the name of the function given in model */
$usersDetails = Models\User::with('products')->get();
```

Now the user will be having the key with **products** inside the query

Now in **blade** you can do the following way to access the products

```
@foreach($users as $user)
    {{ $user->firstname }} - {{ $user->lastname }}

    @foreach($user->product as $product)
        {{ $product->name }}
    @endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score -1):

```
return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Product');
```

but I think you must replace product with user here to get access to product.